# bash + expect, running in background

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, background-process

I'm using expect to establish a persistent ssh connection

```
set stb_ip [lindex $argv 0]

spawn -noecho ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-master-%r@%h:%p -o ConnectTimeout=1 -O exit root@$stb_ip
spawn -noecho ssh -fN -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-master-%r@%h:%p -o ControlPersist=360 -o ConnectTimeout=1 root@$stb_ip
expect {
-re ".*password:" {send "\r"; interact}
}
```

Unfortunately I can't manage to put this into background, I triend expect_background, fork+disconect but no luck.
Even triend running this from another script with

```
excpect -f script.ex param1 param2 &
```

but with no luck. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Heres a proc you can use to login and then interact. I have not tried it with all the ssh Options but I don't see any reason it would not work. Since I use the 8.6 command "try" this is for 8.6 tcl only but you can modify the try to use catch for earlier versions pretty easily.

```
#!/bin/sh
 # the next line restarts using wish \
 exec /opt/usr8.6b.5/bin/tclsh8.6  "$0" ${1+"$@"}

if { [ catch {package require Expect } err ] != 0 } {
    puts stderr "Unable to find package Expect ... adjust your auto_path!";
}
proc login { user password cmdline } {
    set pid [spawn  -noecho {*}$cmdline ] 
    set bad 0;
    set done 0;
    exp_internal 0; # set to one for extensive debug
    log_user 0;     # set to one to watch action
    set timeout 10 
    set passwdcount 0
    set errMsg {} 
    # regexp to match prompt after successfull login you may need to change
    set intialpromptregexp {^.*[\$\#>]}
    expect {
        -i $spawn_id
        -re $intialpromptregexp {
        send_user $expect_out(0,string);
        set done 1 
        }
        -re {.*assword:} {
        if { $passwdcount >= 1 } {
            lappend errMsg "Invalid username or password for user $user"
            set bad 1
        } else {
            exp_send -i $spawn_id  "$password\r"
            incr passwdcount
            exp_continue;
        }
        }
        -re {.*Host key verification failed.} {
        lappend errMsg "Host key verification failed."
        set bad 1
        } 
        -re {.*onnection refused} {
        lappend errMsg "Connection Refused"
        set bad 1
        } 
        -re {.*onnection closed by remote host} {
        lappend errMsg "Connection Refused"
        set bad 1
        } 
        -re {.*Could not resolve hostname (.*): Name or service not known}  {
        lappend errMsg "Host  invalid: Could not resolve hostname in $cmdline : Name or service not known"
        set bad 1
        } 
        -re {\(yes/no\)\?} {
        exp_send -i $spawn_id  "yes\r"
        exp_continue;
        }
        timeout { 
        lappend errMsg "timeout \[[expr { [clock seconds] - $start } ]\]" 
        set bad 1
        }
        fullbuffer {
        lappend errMsg " buffer is full"
        exp_continue;
        }
        eof {
        puts "Eof detected "
        set bad 1
        set done 1 ;
        }
    }
    if { $bad } {
        throw CONNECTION_ERROR [join $errMsg \n ] 
    } 
    return $spawn_id
}
# get login information in somehow in this case from command line 
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set passwd [lindex $argv 1]
set host [lindex $argv 2 ]  
try {
    set spawn_id [login $user $passwd "ssh -X $user@$host" ]
} trap CONNECTION_ERROR a {
    puts "CONNECTION ERROR: $a"
    exit 1
} 
interact 
set exitstatus [ exp_wait -i $spawn_id ];
catch { exp_close -i $spawn_id };
# more clean up here if you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script works in the "foreground"...

```
nohup expect -f script.ex param1 param2 &
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't play well with expect. After execution, there's no ssh process running.

Comment: Two questions... first, what is the point of "interact" when you are putting this in the background?  Second... does this work without touching it in the foreground?

Comment: Good point, I'm new to expect and just triend to de-interact a script I had copied. ;-) And yes, this works fine when run by hand.

Comment: Works fine after removal of 'interact', unfortunately ssh process gets 'defunc' a few seconds after script execution.

Comment: Well, I did a dirty hack: add `sleep 300` at the end of script, and run it throu `expect -f .. &`
If anyone has a better solution - pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I made a long time ago. It does what you want but doesn't use Expect (which I loathe). I don't use it any more, I can't guarantee that it even still works but it should get you going.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Persistent ssh: Automatically create persistent ssh connections using OpenSSH 4.0

[ -z "$USER" ] && USER=`whoami`
MASTERSOCKDIR="/tmp/pssh-$USER"
MASTERSOCK="$MASTERSOCKDIR/%r-%h-%p"

# Check if master is running
output=`ssh -o ControlPath="$MASTERSOCK" -O check "$@" 2>&1`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        case "$output" in
        Control*)
                # Master not running, SSH supports master

                # Figure out socket filename
                socket=`echo "$output" | sed -n -e 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p' -e '1q'`

                # Clean old socket if valid filename
                case "$socket" in
                "$MASTERSOCKDIR"/*) rm -f "$socket" >/dev/null 2>&1 ;;
                esac

                # Start persistent master connection
                if [ ! -d "$MASTERSOCKDIR" ]; then
                        mkdir "$MASTERSOCKDIR"
                        chmod 700 "$MASTERSOCKDIR"
                fi
                ssh -o ControlPath="$MASTERSOCK" -MNf "$@"
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                        echo "$0: Can't create master SSH connection, falling back to regular SSH" >&2
                fi
                ;;
        *)
                # SSH doesn't support master or bad command line parameters
                ERRCODE=$?
                echo "$output" >&2
                echo "$0: SSH doesn't support persistent connections or bad parameters" >&2
                exit $ERRCODE
                ;;
        esac
fi
exec ssh -o ControlPath="$MASTERSOCK" -o ControlMaster=no "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute an expect script in the background use `expect eof` at the end of your expect script. In case you have defined `interact` remove it from your script.

Changed script of OP

```
set stb_ip [lindex $argv 0]

spawn -noecho ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-master-%r@%h:%p -o ConnectTimeout=1 -O exit root@$stb_ip
spawn -noecho ssh -fN -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-master-%r@%h:%p -o ControlPersist=360 -o ConnectTimeout=1 root@$stb_ip
expect {
-re ".*password:" {send "\r"; interact}
}
expect eof
```

An other example  [[1]](https://gist.github.com/nachivpn/ff2e2b8cf647af633127).

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set host "host"
set password "password"

spawn ssh $host

expect {
"(yes/no)?"     {
        send -- "yes\r"
        exp_continue
        }
"*password:*" {
        send -- "$password\r"
        }
}

##Removing this:
#interact 

##And adding this:
expect eof
exit
```